# Не могу найти информацию о том как сформировать или что установить для entity framework core для создания локальной базы данных

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, signalr

создан консольный проект для него был отдельно создан файл appsetting.json. В этом файле есть строка подключения к локальной БД

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=MvcMovie;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
    }
  }
```

Подключаю сервис:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string condb = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<bdContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(condb));
            services.AddSignalR();

        }
```

При срабатывание команды создания выходит ошибка 
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): Не удается найти указанный файл.

Что подключить или установить для решения проблемы. Нужна база mssql локальная, т.е .в mdf файле. Для работы использую visual studio code.

Comment: SQL Server установлен? Строку подключения откуда брали?

Comment: Вообщем я решил использовать sqlite и его провайдер, потому что даже примера найти для core со стройкой подключения к локальной БД mssql server express не смог. С ним sqlite работает нормально. Единственное что понять не могу почему когда я пытаюсь вставить в контекст метод AddRange List<Message> с заполненными данными при сохранении появляется только 1 запись, но ошибок нет, а сам List при этом с несколькими записими в деббагере vs code? Извините за скомканность вопроса заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, если за глупый вопрос, но ответ так и не нашел. Использовал sqlite для работы с локальной  бд, при использовании полноценного mssql сервера подключение с его провайдером проходит успешно. Мой комментарий по нескольким записям в sqlite не актуален, так как я передавал ссылку на объект вместо экземпляра.